# How to create comparator?

Tags: java, compare

How do I create a Comparator that compare the `string` and display the `integer` in reverse order leaving the character at same position. eg `input=10,20,100,a,50` `output` should be `100,50,20,a,10`.

```
class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator<String>{

@Override
 public int compare(String o1, String o2)
 {
    return -o1.compareTo(o2);
 }
```

Comment: how `a> 10` happened? what will be the logic?

Comment: Leaving values at the same position as before is outside the scope of what you can do with a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to define a `Comparator` that would produce the output you want, since a `Comparator` must define a consistent ordering, and your requirements don't.

Consider these two inputs :

```
10,20,100,a,50

10,20,100,a,5
```

In the first, you want the order to be :

```
100,50,20,a,10
```

While in the second you want :

```
100,20,10,a,5
```

You can't define a `Comparator` in which for some inputs "a">"10" while for others "a"<"10".

Answer (score 0):

You can't define Comparator for a string comparison to Integer because we can not compare alphabet with integer value.

so when you use Comaprator or Collection.sort(list<>) will always sort Integer and sort character string.

```
List<String> numAlpha=new ArrayList<String>();

        numAlpha.add("2");
        numAlpha.add("8");
        numAlpha.add("7");
        numAlpha.add("b");
        numAlpha.add("6");

        numAlpha.add("y");
        numAlpha.add("test");
        numAlpha.add("alpha");

        Collections.sort(numAlpha);
        System.out.println(numAlpha.toString());
```

output:
[2, 6, 7, 8, alpha, b, test, y]